# Prime Factorization for Square Roots with unknowns

Tags: roots, prime-factorization

I need to help my daughter with math, but I don't understand it myself.  We need to solve for $x$ and $y$ in the following equation, using prime factorization:

$$\sqrt{1890x} = \sqrt{2100y}$$

Can anyone show me how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear to me that this problem will have a unique solution as written. Can you post the entire question word for word?

Comment: Do you mean $\sqrt {1890\times x}=\sqrt {2100\times y}$?  If so... Why not just drop the square roots?

Comment: To clarify what Lulu means: you would square both sides, thus negating the square root. I can't really help beyond that, though, because I'm not 100% sure what the problem is asking for.

Comment: @lulu I think that what the problem is ultimately going to ask for is a positive $x$ and $y$ with $\gcd(x,y)=1$. The square roots will ensure positivity in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you square both sides, you have

$$1890x = 2100y$$.

Get the prime factorization of those numbers to write

$$2\cdot 3^3\cdot 5\cdot 7 x = 2^23\cdot 5^2 7 y.$$

Cancel all the common factors:

$$9x = 10 y.$$

If $a$ is any integer then $x=10a$, $y=9a$ will solve the equation.  The square roots force $a$ to be positive.

Comment: I was just about to post that! You have made a typo though, because the power of 3 in the factorisation of 1890 is 3, not two, so you should get $9x=10y$

Comment: @lulu  Thanks. The doorbell rang just as I was typing.